# Drupal 7 Form API - Custom Select Theme

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, form-api

I have been searching all day but unable to find any answers - I am sure I am doing it right as worked fine in Drupal 6 and should work fine in Drupal 7.

I want to give a custom theme function to my select element in my form

`$form['field_name'] = array(

        '#type' => 'select',

        '#title' => t('Title Here'),

        '#theme' => 'custom_select',

        '#options' => $values,

);`

I have the theme hook right to declare the new custom theme function but my problem is when using that custom theme function as above I get an empty $variables array which just reads

`Array([element] => null)`

can anyone see what I may be doing wrong? cleared cache, done everything I can think of - any ideas why Drupal is not passing the element data to the theme function? thanks

Comment: post your hook theme. D7 uses variables instead of arguments.

Comment: hi Ben - yes I know it does and posted the answer below - just figured it out now! was a hair puller - thanks for the help though

Comment: Glad you solved it. I was thinking the problem was in hook_theme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well finally figured this one out incase any one else has the problem - make sure you set render element in hook_theme and not variables!

before

`function hook_theme(){`

return array(
'select_currency' => array(
'variables' => array('element' => null),
'file' => 'module_name.theme.inc',
));
}

after

`function hook_theme(){`

return array(
'select_currency' => array(
'render element' => 'element',
'file' => 'module_name.theme.inc',
));
}

I was pulling my hair out until I remembered the render element!